# Trim an array of an arrays (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, trim

I know how to trim all strings in an array (thanks to [this article!](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-trim-all-strings-in-array#trim-all-strings-in-an-array-using-javascript)) through the `map()` method

```js
let a = [' a ', ' b ', ' c '];

let b = a.map(element => {
  return element.trim();
});

console.log(b); // ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

But I was wondering how can I trim an array of arrays?

For example `let x = [[" a ", " b "], [" c ", " d "]]`

Thank you!

P.S: I'm currently learning Javascript.

Comment: *"I'm currently learning Javascript.."* is not a reason to *only* learn by provided code. Where is your attempt to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map over the nested arrays as well.

```js
let data = [[" a ", " b "], [" c ", " d "]]

const result = data.map((d) => d.map((y) => y.trim()));

console.log(result);
```

If you want to flatten out the result, you could use `flatMap()`

```js
let data = [[" a ", " b "], [" c ", " d "]]

const result = data.flatMap((d) => d.map((y) => y.trim()));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the solutions already provided, if you have *n* levels of nested array and you want to trim the string without flattening the array, you can do it recursively as follows.

```js
let arr = [
  [" a ", " b "],
  [" c ", " d ", ["  e", "f "]]
]

function trimRecursively(arr) {
  return arr.map(x => {
    if (Array.isArray(x)) {
      return trimRecursively(x);
    } else {
      return x.trim();
    }
  })
}

console.log(trimRecursively(arr));
```